# LINQ Query Syntax: Group By and OrderBy and take one row

Tags: linq, group-by

Following query will group the records in the Assignment table, added within the given day, by the person assisted and the completed time.

```
(from l in Assignments where ((DateTime)l.AddedLocalTime).Date == TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, TimeZoneInfo.Local).Date
group l by new {l.FkAssistedBy, l.CompletedTime} into groups
orderby  groups.Key.CompletedTime descending
select new { user = groups.Key.FkAssistedBy, groups.Key.CompletedTime })
```

Here, if a particular user has completed multiple assignments within the day, there will be multiple records per the user. But what I want is to group by the user and get ONLY the last completed record per user. How do I use the Take(1) or First() on the above query to get the desired result? I need to output the assistedBy and completedTime fields.

Comment: It is LINQ to Objects?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should work with LINQ to Objects:

```cs
(
    from l in Assignments 
    where ((DateTime)l.AddedLocalTime).Date == TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, TimeZoneInfo.Local).Date
    group l by new { l.FkAssistedBy } into g
    select new 
    {
        user = g.Key.FkAssistedBy,
        CompletedRecord = g.OrderbyDescending(x = c.CompletedTime).FirstOrDefault()
    }
)
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have made myself clear. This is a sub-query of a larger query from which I need the FkAssistedBy and CompletedTime to be projected to joined with the outside query.

Comment: What is the problem? Do that. This query is fully embeddable.